# NpgsqlConnection: Open function does not response

Tags: c#, postgresql

Here is my code. `conn.Open()` waits too much and does not response. Where is my mistake?

I use Postgre 10

```
 var connString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=50738;Database=myDb;User Id=postgres;Password = ab12; ";

                using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: are these information on the connection string correct? You did not provide much information about the error.

Comment: does it ever connect or does it error?

Comment: There is no exception. It waits too much and does not response, as I said my question text.

Comment: @cagin can you connect with pgAdmin4 with the same connection string?

Comment: @zaitsman, yes I can connect.